# What does $('#id option[value=]') select for

Tags: jquery

I'm maintaining some legacy code from a few years ago by someone else and I got an error in the console:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `$('#id option[value=]')`

So, I guess this not valid anymore in the current version of Jquery that this code is deployed under (1.11). I'm not sure what its looking for. Only options with a value attribute?, only options with a value attribute with an empty string as value, all options, etc?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? http://jsfiddle.net/8wv41tkr/

Comment: It may always have been invalid syntax but is just now only showing up with tighter/better checking.

Comment: Your selector is ok, the error should belongs no another thing, please post your whole code.